# Мониторинг системных ресурсов

Tags: windows, память, производительность

Здравствуйте!

OS: Win server 2008

Сейчас пытаюсь оптимизировать некоторый программный код, чтобы приложение кушало меньше памяти. Залез в системный мониторинг ресурсов, чтобы посмотреть, как там обстоят дела. И понял, что ничего там не понимаю =/

Прошу либо пояснить всё это, либо дать ссылку на документ/сайт/мануал, в котором это все расписано:

1. Значения в процессах: Завершено, Рабочий набор, Общий и Частный
2. В расписывании физ. памяти: используется, изменено, ожидание, кэшировано и свободно.
   [скрин](http://www.pictureshack.ru/images/30158_z_8a499b4a.jpg)

Я понимаю, что там есть кое-какие сноски, но этого недостаточно.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В [Gугле](https://www.google.by/search?q=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+windows+2008+r2&oq=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2+windows+2008&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.10336j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) первые же две ссылки:

1. [волне НЕ официально](http://www.oszone.net/10487/resmon)
2. [вполне официально](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc770309(v=ws.10).aspx)

Изучайте:)